# Mass deletion of references in EF Core (Many to Many)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

At present EF Core doesn't support Many-to-Many mapping using Shadow elements but instead needs to use a format like [described here](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many).

I have implemented this, but I am struggling to find a way to do mass deletions. So in the example listed on the EF Core documentation site I would like to delete all the tags associated with a post.

I have tried

`Post.PostTags.Clear()` 
then a `db.SaveChanges()`

but nothing happens.

Whats the correct way to delete a many-to-many relation in EF Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    //Change the model names according to yours
    var post = db.Posts.Include(p => p.PostTags).Single(/*something here*/);
    db.PostTags.RemoveRange(post.PostTags.ToArray());
    db.SaveChanges();
```

It works with me.